# Trying to construct an array from a known map function

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, ecmascript-6

I trying to construct a `docs` array that would work on `docs.maps()` function below. However when I run it I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'uuid' of undefined
```

If I do

```
console.log(docs[1]['_source'].uuid);
```

I get `2` as expected.

**Question**

Can anyone figure out why the map function can't access `uuid` but `console.log()` can?

```
const docs = [{'_id': 1},{'_source': {'uuid': 2}},{'_source': {'@timestamp': 3}}];

const description = dedent`
================================================
${
  docs.map((element) => [
    `Log entry ID: ${element['_id']}`,
    `UUID: ${element['_source'].uuid}`,
    `Timestamp: ${element['_source']['@timestamp']}\n`,
  ].join('\n')).join('--------------------\n')
}
`;

console.log(description);
```

Comment: `_id` and `_source` properties are in different elements of the array.

Comment: `{'_id': 1}` has no `_source` property

Comment: For the current map function, the array should look like
`const docs = [{_id: 1, _source: {'uuid': 2, '@timestamp': 3} }];`

Comment: @Barmar I have checked with the original source code, and `_id` does not have a `_source`. It is the only one that doesn't. The missing error `uuid` is from the second element.

Comment: @CertainPerformance I have checked with the original source code, and `_id` does not have a `_source`. It is the only one that doesn't. The missing error `uuid` is from the second element.

Comment: The point is that different elements have different keys. So you can't access all the same keys in `map()`.

Comment: You get the error when `map()` tries to access the missing `_source.uuid` on the first element.

Comment: @Barmar That is interesting. I can't really grasp how I could add `_source.uuid` to the first element. Could you post how `docs` then would look like?

Comment: I don't know what this data represents. If the objects are different, why do you expect to be able to map it?

Comment: I think you should review how map works. It operates on every member of the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You have to structure like so

```
const docs = [{'_id': 1,'_source': {'uuid': 2,'@timestamp': 3}}];
```